# Turn off actuator security for spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am following a spring-boot tutorial on lynda.com 
https://www.lynda.com/Spring-tutorials/Spring-Boot-Actuator/653258/709599-4.html?autoplay=true
And the presenter simply says turn off the 
management security
This is what the application.yml looks like

```
management:
  security:
  enabled: false
---
spring:
  profiles: dev
server:
  port:8000
---
spring:
  profiles: test
server:
  port:9000
```

And this is what main class looks like

```
package com.frankmoley.boot.essentials.initialbootapp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
public class InitialBootAppApplication {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(InitialBootAppApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api")
    public class ApiController {
        @GetMapping("/greeting")
        public String getGreeting() {
            return "Hey, this is my custom string message!!!";
        }
    }
}
```

Now, there is no explicit login he goes through or authentication taking place here. And if the security is turned off, it should let me see the localhost:8080/mappings and localhost:8080/health should also show me the entire message. 
But, I dont see the extra information.
In my logs, I see this text

```
2018-07-31 13:35:01.048  INFO 5068 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.b.a.e.m.MvcEndpointSecurityInterceptor : Full authentication is required to access actuator endpoints. Consider adding Spring Security or set 'management.security.enabled' to false.
```

Is there a way to set the application.yml somewhere as the default properties file, what am I missing here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have mistake in your yml file. Add indentation for "enabled".

```
management:
  security:
    enabled: false
```

Or you can use property files (.properties), this may be more readable for you:

```
management.security.enabled=false
```

Comment: Oh wow, cant believe , the indentation was the cause, fixed the indentation and it works. Thanks